# run bash scripts using laravel command class gives not found error

Tags: laravel, process, command

I want to run simple bash scripts using laravel command class, but I have not found error.
If I go to `/var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts` and run script from there in command line, then everything is OK.

```
$ sh remove-spaces.sh
```

What is wrong in my Laravel code?

**lowercase.sh**

```
for file in /var/www/mysite/storage/app/img/*; 
do mv "$file" "`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`"; 
done
```

**remove-spaces.sh**

```
for file in /var/www/mysite/storage/app/img/*; 
do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '-'`; 
done
```

**RenamePicturesCommand**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands\Pictures;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class RenamePicturesCommand extends Command
{
    protected $removeSpaces;
    protected $lowercase;
    protected $signature = 'pictures:rename';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->removeSpaces = new Process(['sh /var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts/remove-spaces.sh']);
        $this->lowercase = new Process(['sh /var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts/lowercase.sh']);
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $this->removeSpaces->run();
        if (!$this->removeSpaces->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($this->removeSpaces);
        }
        echo $this->removeSpaces->getOutput();

        $this->lowercase->run();
        if (!$this->lowercase->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($this->lowercase);
        }
        echo $this->lowercase->getOutput();
    }
}
```

error output

```
http@0bb690b74597:/var/www/mysite$ php artisan pictures:rename

   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException

  The command "'sh /var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts/remove-spaces.sh'" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Working directory: /var/www/mysite

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
sh: 1: exec: sh /var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts/remove-spaces.sh: not found

  at app/Console/Commands/Pictures/RenamePicturesCommand.php:59
     55▕         // execute command
     56▕         $this->removeSpaces->run();
     57▕         // executes after the command finishes
     58▕         if (!$this->removeSpaces->isSuccessful()) {
  ➜  59▕             throw new ProcessFailedException($this->removeSpaces);
     60▕         }
     61▕         echo $this->removeSpaces->getOutput();
     62▕
     63▕

      +13 vendor frames
  14  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Comment: Not related to the issue - but why do you want to use shell script for renaming files. It can be done with the **Storage** facade easily without having the need to run shell script.

Comment: First, use the Storage manager that comes with laravel. `exec("sh your_script.sh", $output); $this->comment( implode( PHP_EOL, $output ) );`

Answer (score 2):

You may try to provide the command and argument as two separate items in the commands array

```php
namespace App\Console\Commands\Pictures;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class RenamePicturesCommand extends Command
{
    protected $removeSpaces;
    protected $lowercase;
    protected $signature = 'pictures:rename';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->removeSpaces = new Process(['sh', '/var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts/remove-spaces.sh']);
        $this->lowercase = new Process(['sh', '/var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts/lowercase.sh']);

        //Or you can use Process::fromShellCommandline
        //$this->removeSpaces =Process::fromShellCommandline('sh /Volumes/samsung-250/Sites/stackoverflow/storage/app/scripts/lowercase.sh');
        //$this->lowercase =Process::fromShellCommandline('sh /Volumes/samsung-250/Sites/stackoverflow/storage/app/scripts/remove-spaces.sh');
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $this->removeSpaces->run();
        if (!$this->removeSpaces->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($this->removeSpaces);
        }
        echo $this->removeSpaces->getOutput();

        $this->lowercase->run();
        if (!$this->lowercase->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($this->lowercase);
        }
        echo $this->lowercase->getOutput();
    }
}
```

You can also achieve the same results with **Storage** facade without any shell script

```php
namespace App\Console\Commands\Pictures;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\LazyCollection;

class RenamePicturesCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'pictures:rename';


    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Renaming pictures...');
        $this->newLine(2);

        $files = LazyCollection::make(Storage::disk('local')->files('img'))
            //Remove dotfiles
            ->reject(fn($filePath) => Str::startsWith($filePath, '.'));

        $progress = $this->output->createProgressBar($files->count());
        $progress->start();

        $modified = [];

        $files->each(function ($file) use ($progress, &$modified) {

            $new = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $file));

            $temp = ['old' => $file, 'new' => $new, 'status' => 'success'];

            if(! Storage::disk('local')->move($file, $new)) {
                $temp['status'] = 'failed';
                $temp['new'] = $file;
            }

            $modified[] = $temp;

            $progress->advance();
        });

        
        $this->newLine(2);
        $this->info('Finished Renaming pictures');
        $this->newLine(2);
        $this->table(['Old', 'New', 'Status'], $modified);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second solution is interesting, but it doesn't work. It gives me error `File already exists at path: img/glass/_work/2013--10-01-16.58.20.jpg`
But in reality there is no dublicate file `app/Console/Commands/Pictures/RenamePicturesCommand.php:71  Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::move("img/glass/_work/2013- 10-01-16.58.20.jpg", "img/glass/_work/2013--10-01-16.58.20.jpg")`
Here is the screenshot
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/-d_nX6E2FuRaxg

Comment: @schel4ok Does the script solution work properly? Under the hood **Storage::move** uses php **rename** which will overwrite a file if it exists, except for on windows os where it will throw an error.

Comment: what do you mean "Does the script solution work properly?"

Comment: @schel4ok The solution involving shell script as per the original question. Using either **Process::fromShellCommandline** or **new Process** & separating the command **sh** and arguments as two elements of the array passed to **new Process**

Comment: 1) My initial solution with new Process always gives me Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException    ➜  69▕             throw new ProcessFailedException($this->removeSpaces); The command "'sh /var/www/mysite/storage/app/scripts/remove-spaces.sh'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) And no even one file renamed.

Comment: 2) Solution with new Process & separating the command sh and arguments works only if there are only files with spaces and uppercase letters. When there is one file either without space or without UPPERCASE letter it gives me Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException on the line 69 (if find file without spaces or line 78 if file without UPPERCASE letters). In this case it renames files until he found one file without spaces or without UPPERCASE.

Comment: Actually your solution with **Storage->move** works absolutely the same way. If it finds file, which doesn't match criteria, then it just fall with error. But I found the way how to make it works.

Comment: if($file === $new) { $temp['status'] = 'failed'; $temp['new'] = $file; } else { Storage::disk('local')->move($file, $new); $temp['status'] = 'success'; }

Comment: I just faced another error when $new file exists. So I changed IF a little bit `if( Storage::disk('local')->exists($new) ) {
                $temp['status'] = 'untouched';
                $temp['new'] = $file;
                $untouched++;
            } else {
                Storage::disk('local')->move($file, $new);
                $temp['status'] = 'renamed';
                $renamed++;
            }`

Comment: Now it works without any problems recursively. Thanks for your help!